# Flask Admin Custom View

Tags: python-2.7, flask, flask-admin

I am pretty new to Flask/Flask-Admin.
I have followed the tutorial on flask admin and managed to get the admin panel working but slightly lost on how to get the below things implemented.
https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/tree/master/examples/auth

- When logged in as a normal user I can only see "home" page.
  How can I expose other views to "normal user" and restrict actions such as read only etc.
- I have created a "baseview" which is not associated with any other models as below:

> ```
> class SitesView(MyBaseView):
>     @expose('/')
>     def index(self):
>     return self.render('views/testviews.html')
>
> admin.add_view(SitesView(name='Test views', endpoint='test views'))
> ```

and html as below:

```
{% extends 'admin/master.html' %}
{% block body %}
{{ super() }}
{% if current_user.has_role('view1') %}
<a href="#">Site1</a>
{% endif %}
{% if current_user.has_role('view2') %}
<a>Site2</a>
{% endif %}
{% if current_user.has_role('view3') %}
<a>Site3</a>
{% endif %}
{% if current_user.has_role('view4') %}
<a>Site4</a>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

This gives me a new tab with different views with works as expected.

What I am trying to achieve here is when user click the Site1 link they go to Site1 page within flask-admin interface but I am not sure how to do that. I could create a new route for this but the problem is I can't(don't know how to) extend flask admin template.

For example this works but it redirect the page outside flask-admin template:

> ```
> @app.route('/views/')
> def views():
>     return render_template('views/views1.html')
> ```

and modified the templates>admin>index.html page with below:

```
<ul class="lead text-center list-group">
    {% if current_user.has_role('view1') %}
        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="{{ url_for('views') }}">View1</a></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% if current_user.has_role('view2') %}
        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">View2</a></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% if current_user.has_role('view3') %}
        <li class="list-group-item">View3</li>
    {% endif %}
    {% if current_user.has_role('view4') %}
        <li class="list-group-item">View4</li>
    {% endif %}
</ul
```

I want to build the whole web site using flask admin so that I can keep user experience consistence. Am I doing this the wrong way?

Thanks for your time.

Please do let me know if you want me to provide more information on this issue.

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 2):

So after going through documentations and tutorials I have found the solution to my issue.
For my first question:

> When logged in as a normal user I can only see "home" page. How can I
>   expose other views to "normal user" and restrict actions such as read
>   only etc.

We can do this by overwriting our view functions is_accessible method as below:

```
def is_accessible(self):
    if not current_user.is_active or not current_user.is_authenticated:
        return False

    if current_user.has_role('superuser') or current_user.has_role('user') or current_user.has_role('view1'):
        return True

    return False
```

For my second question we just need to give the endpoint as for our BaseView as below:

```
class MyView(BaseView):
    @expose('/')
    def index(self):
        return self.render('views.html')

admin.add_view(MyView(name='Custom Views', endpoint='customviews'))
```

And then in your jinja template you need to call it:

```
href="{{ url_for('customviews.index') }}
```

Just one thing to note, doing this:

```
current_user.has_role('superuser') or current_user.has_role('user') or current_user.has_role('view1')
```

could get quite messy if we have so many roles, not sure how we would approach this but hoping this will help someone.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but for the following code

```
current_user.has_role('superuser') or current_user.has_role('user') or current_user.has_role('view1')
```

What I like to do is having a `hybrid_property` (available on both Peewee and SQLAlchemy) inside my User class that consolidates these properties. So it'd look something like this:

```
@hybrid_property
def user_has_administrative_rights(self):
    return self.has_role('superuser') or self.has_role('user')
```